# Adding two broken rows using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a file which has **header** at first row and then other data at remaining rows. I want to check whether all rows has equal no of data with header.

For example: if header has `10 count` then I want all my remaining rows to have `10` data each so there will be no error while loading the data.

Suppose in line `5` and `6` there are only `5` data each.So,i want to combine these two rows in such case.
[image]

My expected output is(Row 5 has the merged data)

[image]

There may such breakable data in many rows of the file.So, i just want to scan whole file and will merge the two rows when such cases are seen.

So, I tried using:

```
$splitway=' '
$firstLine = Get-Content -Path $filepath -TotalCount 1
$firstrowheader=$firstLine.split($splitway,System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
$requireddataineachrow=$firstrowheader.Count
echo $requireddataineachrow
```

The above code will give me `10` since my header is having 10 data.

```
For ($i = 1; $i -lt $totalrows; $i++) {
   $singleline=Get-Content $filepath| Select -Index $i
   $singlelinesplit=$singleline.split($splitway,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
   if($singlelinesplit.Count -lt $requireddataineachrow){
     $curr=Get-Content $filepath| Select -Index $i 
     $next=Get-Content $filepath| Select -Index $i+1 
     Write-Host (-join($curr, " ", $next))
   } 
   echo $singlelinesplit.Count
}
```

I tested using `Write-Host (-join($curr, " ", $next))` to join two lines but it's not giving the correct output.

`echo $singlelinesplit.Count` is showing correct result:

[image]

My whole data is:

```
billing   summary_id  offer_id   vendor_id  import_v   system_ha  rand_dat  mand_no  sad_no   cad_no
11        23             44       77        88         99         100       11        12        500
1111      2333           4444    6666       7777777   8888888888   8888888888888  9999999999 1111111111111 2000000000
33333      444444     As per new account ddddddd gggggggggggg wwwwwwwwwww bbbbbbbbbbb qqqqqqqqqq rrrrrrrrr 5555555
22 33 44 55 666<CR>
42 65 66 55  244
11        23             44       76        88         99         100       11        12        500
1111      2333           new document    664466       7777777   8888888888   8888888888888  9999999999 111111144111 200055000
```

My whole code if needed is:

```
cls
$filepath='D:\test.txt'
$splitway=' '


$totalrows=@(Get-Content $filepath).Length

write-host $totalrows.gettype()

$firstLine = Get-Content -Path $filepath -TotalCount 1

$firstrowheader=$firstLine.split($splitway,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

$requireddataineachrow=$firstrowheader.Count

For ($i = 1; $i -lt $totalrows; $i++) {
   $singleline=Get-Content $filepath| Select -Index $i
   $singlelinesplit=$singleline.split($splitway,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
   if($singlelinesplit.Count -lt $requireddataineachrow){
     $curr=Get-Content $filepath| Select -Index $i 
     $next=Get-Content $filepath| Select -Index $i+1 
     Write-Host (-join($curr, " ", $next))
   } 
   echo $singlelinesplit.Count
}
```

Comment: Assuming the file format is exactly as you've posted, then this is impossible. Row 3 appears to have either 13 data or only 3 columns, depending on whether a single space is a delimiter or not...

Comment: [As per new account ] is considered a single word but currently i need to merge two lines escaping this issue. if you can help me to get the count of row 3 as 10 it would be also much helpful

Comment: Is the `<CR>` a CR character (`0xd`) _in isolation_, or is it a regular CRLF newline (`0xd 0xa`)?

Comment: it's a CRLF newline

Comment: @mklement0 or you can help me by providing the logic to see if there is <CR> and will merge two lines... since in breakable row i am seeing <CR>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: It seems that instances of string `<CR>` are a *verbatim* part of your input file, in which case the following solution should suffice:

```sh
(Get-Content -Raw sample.txt) -replace '<CR>\s*', ' ' | Set-Content sample.txt
```

---

Here's a solution that makes the following assumptions:

- `<CR>` is just a *placeholder* to help visualize an *actual newline* in the input file.
- Only data rows with *fewer* columns than the header row require fixing (as Mathias points out, your data is ambiguous, because a column value such as `As per new account` technically comprises *three* values, due to its embedded spaces).
- Such a data row can blindly be joined with the subsequent line (only) to form a complete data row.

```sh
# Create a sample file.
@'
billing   summary_id  offer_id   vendor_id  import_v   system_ha  rand_dat  mand_no  sad_no   cad_no
11        23             44       77        88         99         100       11        12        500
1111      2333           4444    6666       7777777   8888888888   8888888888888  9999999999 1111111111111 2000000000
33333      444444     As per new account ddddddd gggggggggggg wwwwwwwwwww bbbbbbbbbbb qqqqqqqqqq rrrrrrrrr 5555555
22 33 44 55 666
42 65 66 55  244
11        23             44       76        88         99         100       11        12        500
1111      2333           new document    664466       7777777   8888888888   8888888888888  9999999999 111111144111 200055000
'@ > sample.txt

# Read the file into the header row and an array of data rows.
$headerRow, $dataRows = Get-Content sample.txt

# Determine the number of whitespace-separated columns.
$columnCount = (-split $headerRow).Count

# Process all data rows and save the results back to the input file:
#  Whenever a data row with fewer columns is encountered,
#  join it with the next row.
$headerRow | Set-Content sample.txt
$joinWithNext = $false
$dataRows |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($joinWithNext) {
      $partialRow + ' ' + $_
      $joinWithNext = $false
    }
    elseif ((-split $_).Count -lt $columnCount) {
      $partialRow = $_
      $joinWithNext = $true
    }
    else {
      $_
    }
  } | Add-Content sample.txt
```